# disconnect event on Signalr Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR without proxy in my client

I want to handle a disconnect event in signalR when the browser closes, then initialize another hub in my application

for detail see this code

```
var firstHub = jqu.hubConnection();
firstHub.url = "http://localhost:9351/signalr";
var socket = firstHub.createHubProxy('testHub');
var webSocketClass = {
   id=''
};
socket.on("sendAll", function (name, message) {
    console.log(name + " " + message);
});

firstHub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
    socket.invoke("send", webSocketClass);
```

This is the first hub, the second looks like this:

```
var secondHub = jqu.hubConnection();
secondHub.url = "http://localhost:9351/signalr";
var secondSocket = secondHub.createHubProxy("onlineUserHub");
secondSocket.on("send", function (user) {
    console.log(user);
});
 secondHub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
        secondSocket.invoke("onLineUserChanged", webSocketClass);
    });
```

After the first hub is disconnected I'd like to send a value to the second hub.

The following code did not work:

```
 socket.on("onDisconnect", function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In signalr 2.2 for check connection closed you can try this

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();

var hub = connection.createHubProxy('TestHub');

//the most important part
connection.disconnected(function() {
    alert('Disconnected!');
});

connection.start();
```

This event may fire immediately or after several attempts to reconnect